# How to size LRU cache for custom data type

Tags: java, android, caching, lru

When using LRU for bitmap the number `1024` is used in the calculation for the number of items to cache. I want to cache a custom datatype. Say MyDog. How do I size the cache? Also, does anyone have a simple example? I have the google example for bitmap, but it may be overkill for my simple (?) application. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

For the sake of argument, say that each MyDog object is computed locally but is expensive to compute (which is why I am caching).

Comment: you have to figure out a size measurement for you object. If all object are considered of equivalent size, `1` can be a good size, but a precise occupation of memory can be better. Then you need to figure out the maximum amount of units you want to store. This depends on the memory on the device, the amount of items you may encounter, how long you need to keep them...

Comment: For bitmaps, the actual size in memory is usually used as the measurement, as it varies a lot between images, and it allows to give a size for the cache of a arbitrary fraction of the RAM.

Comment: MyDog has 20 String fields and related methods. I wanted to follow the bitmap model, but I don't have to. So if I choose the other approach: Is it safe to just pick an arbitrary size like 10? If so, what number is too low? and what number is too high? I am concerned about overhead of storage as explained in the official docs.

Comment: @user3093402 just use 1

Comment: @pskink @njzk2 My apologies if I seem to be belaboring this; I just want to be sure. Are you saying I should use ` mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, MyDog>(1)`?

Comment: no i said you should use size of one item == 1, in constructor use how many items you want to keep in the cache

Comment: 10, or whatever size you want for your cache depends on the size of one object (which in turn depends on the size of the strings you'll store there), on the number of elements you will be manipulating, the amount of memory ...

Comment: for example, if you have 10000 object in a DB, and you are displaying them in a list, and you are using a LruCache, and your user is scrolling, a cache size of 10 is useless.

Comment: You can adjust the size of your cache by starting at an arbitrary value, and measuring simultaneously the amount of memory used and the number of cache miss during the use of your app.